# Restructure JS object to fit binding MVC model

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I have a javascript object with nested objects obtained by a plugin saved in a variable called 'json':

```
// var json:
Object {0: Object, 1: Object}
    0: country
        countryCapital: Object
        ministers: Array[1]
    1: country
        countryCapital: Object
        ministers: Array[3]

// Should be restructured to fit MVC models
World
    Country Array [2]
        Capital: Object
        Minister: Array [1]
```

Because I'm sending the data using jQuery-ajax to a MVC controller I'm trying to rename/restructure them to bind them to a MVC Model so I can send the whole 'World' object as 1 parameter.

```
// Controller
[HttpPost]
public void Save(World world) 

// Model structure:
World
    * Country (list)
        1 Capital
        * Minister (list)
```

How do I convert the javascript object to the right structure that fits the Model parameter? Do I need to loop everything or can it be done in a better way?

UPDATE:

json object update, it's a lot of data so I simplified it.

```
// World
{
    "0": { // Country
        "ministers": 
        {
            "objects": [
                {
                    "name": "name1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "name2"
                }
            ]
        },
        "countryCapital": {
          "name": "...",
        }
    },
    "1": { // Country
        "ministers": 
        {
            "objects": [
                {    
                    "name": "name1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "name2"
                }
            ]
        },
        "countryCapital": {
            "name": "...",
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide json then object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution thanks to teo van kot using jQuery map.

```
var world = {}

$.map(json, function (value, i) {
    if (i == "countryCapital") { 
       world.Capital = value 
    }
    if (i == "ministers") {
        world.Minister= value

        $.each(value, function (j, minister) {
            world.Minister[j].Name = minister.name;
            delete minister.name;
        });
    }
}, world);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're searching for [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/).

At the background it's looping your collection but it much cleaner to use it in your case.

Comment: It's pretty simple to map this without including an entire library and the question doesn't ask for jQuery

Comment: My mistake ... I cmd+f the page for jquery but it wasnt there the first time ... unless I am being stupid [edit: it was there at the start, sorry again :) ]

Comment: I'm using jQuery and the tag was there at start but I'm open for all (the best) solutions. I'm trying both possibilities.

Comment: @Sam @CarbonDry well, i gess `map()` is the best =)

Comment: Well, the answer I provided will create 'world' as a single param for you and build your structure in the way $.map does. So whatever is best for you.

Comment: @Sam actually we need actual json structure before and after

Answer (score 1):

Updated to use your example json. [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stevewbrown/j3gd3se0/3/)

```js
var world = {}

for (var countryIteration in originalObject) {
 var country = originalObject[countryIteration];
  world[countryIteration] = { //you need to this because you need dynamic keys.
    capital : country.countryCapital.name,
    ministers : country.ministers.objects
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `for each`? That's not JS.

Comment: It was written in a psuedo way, I have updated the code and here is a working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/stevewbrown/j3gd3se0/1/embedded/result/

Comment: Is this a better solution than using the jQuery map functionality you think? It uses less code to accomplish the same so it looks that way.

Comment: With your example you posted, you still have to create the world object, and you are creating an `$.each` loop within `$.map`'s  internal loop. Therfore in this example less code is used.